# Script message handler not working

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am trying to inject a custom WebKit script message handler. My controller is correctly loaded and the view as well. However, on the JS side (from the Safari console), `window.webkit.messageHandlers` is empty. Any idea why? My app is using iOS 8.1 but even by upgrading to 9.2, it did not work.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

public class FooController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    private var wkWebView: WKWebView?

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let o = WKUserContentController()
        o.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "foo")
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = o

        self.wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: config)
        self.view.addSubview(self.wkWebView!)

        self.wkWebView!.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("foo", withExtension: "html")!))
    }

    public func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("foo")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`webkit.messageHandlers` is not an Array. It is a `UserMessageHandlersNamespace`.

Try

```js
var message = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "dictionary": {"name": "foo"}}
webkit.messageHandlers.foo.postMessage(message);
```

In your message handler.

```swift
public func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
    let body = message.body
    if let dict = body as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        print(dict)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Onato, thanks for your answer. I know `messageHandlers` is an object. But it has no key at all, and especially `foo` is missing.

Comment: Your swift code worked fine for me. Can you post how you are calling your message handler or checking for the existence of "foo"?

Comment: Arf. Just retested and it works fine. Sorry for the confusion.
However, I have a different issue now. I cannot post any custom data. I tried to post a dictionary with 2 strings and another dictionary and the body I received only included a single string. Not a big deal, but do you know anything about that?

Comment: Awesome! It works fine. I was trying to cast the body as a `NSDictionary` but it did not work as expected.

Answer (score -2):

In the below javascript code, message is mandatory.

```
var message = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "dictionary": {"name": "foo"}}
webkit.messageHandlers.foo.postMessage(message);
```

The following javascript code without the message parameter,

`webkit.messageHandlers.foo.postMessage();`

did not invoke the `func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage)` as expected